# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCPicker" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu, expo

I'm trying to implement drop down menu in my react native project, when testing with expo it works perfectly but while testing on development build it returns an error and this makes me feel it will cause a problem in development.

this is the error

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCPicker" was not found in the UIManager
```

I'm using `react-native-picker-select` and according to the blog I need to install `expo install @react-native-community/picker` to fix it which I've done but problem persists.

this is my code

```
<View style={{margin: 10, backgroundColor:'lightgray', borderRadius:10}}>
<RNPickerSelect
placeholder={{ label: "Select your truck size", value: null }}
             onValueChange={(value) => setTest(value)}
             items={[
                 { label: "Test1", value: "test 1" },
                 { label: "Test2", value: "Test 2" },
                 { label: "Test3", value: "Test 3" },
                 
             ]}
         />
    </View>
```

Comment: According to `react-native-picker-select` doc, you should install `@react-native-picker/picker`. See [https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select).

Comment: I already done that

Comment: Maybe some cache issue or dependency linkage issue. Please also post your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure you have the below dependency installed (update version accordingly).

```
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.3.1",
```

Please see: https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select#versioning